# How does adding んで to verb stem change it

Tags: verbs

For example 学 - 学んで

& 死　ー　死んで

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the conjugation of verbs ending in ぶ and ぬ to create the [て-form](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/teform).

休む - 休んで

飲む - 飲んで

払う - 払って

寝る - 寝て

話す - 話して

Suggest you study the て-form conjugations.